# Yii framework 1.1 get the http request Header in Controller action

Tags: php, curl, yii

The API url is www.example.com/api/users?name=test

the curl command curl -H "Connection:keep-alive \n User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 \n Accept:application/json" http://www.example.com/api/users?name=test

in the API controller user action, how to get the header information

```
public function actionUsers()  
    {  
       $this->_checkAuth();  

        // Get Accept type info ???
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`CHttpRequest::acceptTypes`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#acceptTypes-detail) which:

> Returns user browser accept types, null if not present.

`CHttpRequest` is a default component and can be accessed via `Yii::app()->request`:

```
public function actionUsers()  
{  
    $this->_checkAuth();
    $types = Yii::app()->request->acceptTypes;
}
```